# What does -a "${1%_something}" do in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to understand this [bash script](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/06bcb63a0b42ed24ef7509c3352e2cf45d139a5e/5.7/docker-entrypoint.sh). There are some lines of code that I can't explain:

the first one is the if condition on line 4:

```
if [ ! -d '/var/lib/mysql/mysql' -a "${1%_safe}" = 'mysqld' ]; then
```

Could someone please explain me, what does the expression -a "${1%_safe}" = 'mysqld' do?

Next on the line 38:

```
set -- "$@" --init-file="$TEMP_FILE"
```

What does this statement?

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It removes the suffix `_safe` from the first argument passed to the script `$1` and compares it to `mysqld`. If the suffix is not present, it removes nothing (but still performs the comparison).

See the section on substring removal on [this page](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) for more details on string manipulation in Bash.

The `-a` is used to perform a logical AND between the two conditions inside the `test`/`[` command. Often, people prefer not to do this, especially when the separate conditions are complex, instead opting to use `if [ first condition ] && [ second condition ]`. As [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) points out in the comments, the `-a` switch [is discouraged by the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128_16).

[`set`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) is a Bash built-in command, which allows you to modify options in the current shell. In many shell commands, `--` is used to separate options from arguments, so this runs `set` with no options and passes `"$@"` (the arguments passed to the script) and an additional argument `--init-file="$TEMP_FILE"`.

Comment: Note that the POSIX standard itself discourages use of `-a` in favor of two separate `test` commands.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation! This helped me to understand the script! Very good answer!